# Excel: Autofill B2 from B1 if A1 matchs A2

Tags: excel, excel-2013

In this table, how can we do the following:

```
One | uno                 One | uno                One | uno
Two | dos  --manually-->  Two | los dos            Two | los dos 
Ten | diez                Ten | diez               Ten | diez
Two | dos                 Two | dos     --auto-->  Two | los dos
```

That is, if a replace the first *dos* with *los dos*, and since *Two* is repeated, how can *dos* be automatically replaced with *los dos*?

The idea is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116312/excel-if-a1-a2-then-b1-b2-how-to-do-that) but without having to create a different source data table. 
I am translating a two-language glossary that has some entries repeated, so I do not want to translate them twice.

Comment: This will need to be done in vba using a worksheet_change event.

Comment: How exactly? Can you provide like a tutorial @scott-craner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Vlookup`. you have to Enter the formula in next `C:C` cell.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,A:A:B:B,2,FALSE)
```

After done Copy Cell C:C and paste it as values in B:B
Hope this help.